# Select records from a table where all other records with same foreign key have a certain value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a the following table

```
ItemStatus
----------
id
item_id
status
```

I want to select all item_ids where the status for every record with that item_id in the table is A.

For example if the records were like this:

```
id    item_id    status
-----------------------
1        1          A
2        1          B
3        2          A
4        2          A
5        3          B
```

Then the only item_id I would get back is 2.

Comment: ok means 1 will not come as it has A and B both... 2 will come as it has A only... right??

Comment: okies.. I believe JBrooks solution is working...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    select item_id
    from YourTable
    group by item_id
    having sum(case when status='A' then 1 else 0 end) = count(1)
```

Comment: I actually like this one better than my own suggestion.  Looks like it would perform better in a large data set.  Upvoting.

Comment: Thanks, also thought he might next want to do where all are B, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct item_id
from ItemStatus
where status = 'A'
and item_id not in
(
    select item_id
    from ItemStatus
    where status != 'A'
    or status is null
)
```

results in list of item_ids that appear as A at least once and never appear as anything else

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id
FROM your_table t1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM your_table t2
        WHERE t1.item_id = t2.item_id AND t2.status <> 'A'
    )
```

In plain English: select every `item_id` for which there is no row with status different from 'A'.

**--- EDIT ---**

Variation of [Shark's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8905071/533120):

```
SELECT item_id
FROM your_table
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING min(status) = 'A' AND max(status) = 'A'
```

This has a chance of being optimized quite nicely by the DBMS, provided you have an index on {item_id, status}. Here is the SQL Server execution plan:

[image]